# Getting lists from subdictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python, and getting pretty excited about dictionaries. They let me name everything so that I don't have to remember field positions, and seem to make more solid code.  But, right now I'm faced with extracting the lists (1,2,3,4) and (5,6,7,8) from this dict of dicts.  Any ideas??  And... this code is the heart of a stochastic modeling program, so I need to be fast fast. 
Cheers!

```
evnt = {'m1':{'rate':1, 'val':5 },
        'm2':{'rate':2, 'val':6 },
        'd1':{'rate':3, 'val':7 },
        'd2':{'rate':4, 'val':8 }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one obvious way is a list-comprehension, and if it is not fast enough for you then you may need to consider a different data structure.

```
>>> [v['rate'] for v in evnt.itervalues()]
[4, 3, 1, 2]
```

(*note:* just `.values()` for python3)

And no, you can't get them in order (without sorting) because your dict isn't ordered in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is short, so you should be better off without itertools:

```
zip(*(item.values() for item in evnt.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

Check section 5.1.4

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

```
rates = [x['rate'] for x in evnt.values()]
values = [x['val'] for x in evnt.values()]
```